# Angular 7 - best way to get updates from the server to app

Tags: angular, api, server, updates

I 'm developing angular7 messages service (user to user) for my site. 
At the moment I'm getting updates from the server (Yii2 REST API) each 3 min by the interval. (code is below)

Is it an appropriate practice? What is the most convenient way to get updates from the server?

```
export class NotificationDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  public notifications;
  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getNotSeen();
  }

  getNotSeen():void {
    this.notificationService.getUpdates()
      .subscribe( response => {
        if (!response.error) {
          if (response.notifications) {
            this.notifications = response.notifications;
          }
          this.toBeUpdated();
        }
      });
  }

  toBeUpdated(){
    interval(3*60*1000)
      .pipe(flatMap(()=> this.notificationService.getUpdates()))
      .subscribe( response => {
        if (!response.error) {
          if (response.notifications) {
            this.notifications = response.notifications;
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best form is use SSE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events if your API response with header like as:

```
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
```

you can make the getUpdates in notificationService  :

```
getUpdates(){
 let source = new EventSource('http://serverip:port/get_mydata');
 source.addEventListener('message', response => {
   const response = JSON.parse(response);    
   return reponse;    
});
```

}

And toBeUpdated in your NotificationDropdownComponent

```
toBeUpdated(){
   this.notificationService.getUpdates().subscribe( response => {
        if (!response.error) {
          if (response.notifications) {
            this.notifications = response.notifications;
          }
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this approach.